# Always plugged in solution with battery backup

Tags: charger, battery-operated, circuit-protection

I am trying to design an micro-controller based solution which is always plugged in and has a battery backup in case of power failure. I am using an SMPS power supply rated 15V, 1.4A which is always plugged in, a low voltage regulator with BC547 to regulate charging and an SLA battery rated 12V, 11.2Ah as a backup. Below is the circuit I am trying to build.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgwU1K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Few questions I have are

- I need to have a reverse polarity protection for the charger and load and stop any current from flowing back to the charger when there is no power. How to achieve this? I tried to add D1 and D2 as shown in the circuit, however it looks like D1 will not help in reverse polarity protection for the charging section.
- Can this solution float indefinitely without damaging the battery? or should I use a solution with relays (i.e one for charging cutoff and another for backup switchover)

Comment: Are you designing it for educational purposes or are you not aware that they exist a cheap solution to this problem you facing? That plugs in the mains, chargers the sla battery and also outputs 12V and 5V and will automatically switch to battery power if there's a power failure. In addition it also has reverse polarity protection, over charge and discharge protection...

Comment: I am designing this to be used in a product. Do you have the circuit diagram or references to the existing solutions you mentioned?

Comment: https://www.diyelectronics.co.za/store/solar-management-modules/2159-solar-power-manager-for-12v-lead-acid-battery-v10.html. This is made by DFRobot for SLA batteries.

Comment: Thats a solar power manager and it is not cheap! Do you have the circuit diagram?

Comment: Firstly if you took the time to read the document attached you would have realized it is powered in two ways, first through the mains via an adapter and secondly through a solar panel if you want too. Also considering the plethora of features on this board it is in retrospect value for money. However coming back to your point, a good DIY YouTuber by the name of Great Scott has implemented reverse protection circuitry in detail and made a video WITH circuit diagrams.

Comment: I am not going to post his solution because it will be wrong just to copy and paste someone else's work on this platform. So just watch his video on YouTube and hope it helps

Comment: And the power output of 12V with just 1.4A seems too low to charge an 11.2A SLA battery and will, therefore, take a long time. I assume you already got these components like the power supply and battery so you don't have much budget left over. But this is not going to a very efficient system that you are implementing. I would buy the 5V version of the dfrobot battery manager board which has tons of protection features and just use a 12V boost converter at the out of the board since all you require is 600mA peak current. https://wiki.dfrobot.com/Solar_Power_Manager_5V_SKU__DFR0559

Comment: A simple reverse protection may not work in my case, because I am connecting the load in parallel while battery is being charged and the load should work even without a battery. Also I am trying to stop any feed from battery back to the charger while charger is off.